# 2 functions in the same button during submitting the form

Tags: javascript, html, django-templates

I want to submit a form , the story that what i want exactly is when i click on the button submit" if there was an error(fields not filled) , show me message and go to a specific **"id"** section in the body  otherwise it will jump automatically to new **section tag**,

I have applied that on a the button submit like that :

```
  <script>
    function validate() {
    if (form.errors){
      return alert('{{ message }}');
      document.getElementById('firstsectionid').scrollIntoView();
    } 
    else{
      document.getElementById('nextsectionid').scrollIntoView();
}

   </script>
```

**code button submit:**

```
  <button class="floated" href='#nextsectionid' onclick="validate()">Next</button>
```

But it doesn't give any result , help please. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script>
    function validate() {
    if (form.errors){
      return alert('{{ message }}');
      // the line below will never run with a 'return' above it.
      document.getElementById('firstsectionid').scrollIntoView();
    } 
    else{
      document.getElementById('nextsectionid').scrollIntoView();
}

   </script>
```

try this

```
  <script>
    function validate() {
    if (form.errors){
      document.getElementById('firstsectionid').scrollIntoView();
      return alert('{{ message }}');
    } 
    else{
      document.getElementById('nextsectionid').scrollIntoView();
}

   </script>
```

Comment: Hi @ Alex, the same thing there was no result...

Comment: any errors in the console? I assume `form` is defined somewhere?

Comment: am developing a django application, i just said "form.errors"because i have passed the "form" parameter,on a dictionnary exactly on the views.py....

Comment: here it 's the error onthe console "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"